Show Thumbnail Image on the right in Remote Push Notification on iOS
How can I show a thumbnail image within the push notification on iOS? Screenshots at the bottom
SetUp seems to be working as I get the icon, title & body within the payload as well as the image that can be seen, when you 3d tap on the notification, just the thumbnail I can't make work.
Payload looks like this at the moment and I think I need to change something here to make it work.
const message = {
    apns: {
      payload: {
        aps: { 
          alert: {
            title: title,
            body: body,
            image: imageURL
          },
          'mutable-content': 1
        },
        'media-url': imageURL,
      },
      fcm_options: {
        image: imageURL, 
      },
    },
    data: {
      articleId: articleId,
      'media-url': imageURL, 
    },
    tokens: tokens,
  };

[thumbnail image current look](https://i.sstatic.net/5VL5PmHO.png)
What i tried so far:

ChatGPT:

{
  "aps": {
    "alert": {
      "title": "New Message",
      "body": "You have received a message with an image!"
    },
    "mutable-content": 1
  },
  "image-url": "https://example.com/path/to/image.jpg"
}


Blog: https://medium.com/@lucasgoesvalle/custom-push-notification-with-image-and-interactions-on-ios-swift-4-ffdbde1f457

StackOverlow: how to display image in ios push notification?


All didn't get me to the thumbnail, just the image when you tap on the notification
how it looks
how it should look

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
